# Is it possible to control the 3D animation's movement in Unity script?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have this golfer [animation](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/22253). It is quite smooth movement ant the best I can find in golfer animation.
But its movements are always the same pattern.
For example, if I like to use the model to represent real person's movements outside in playing golf. Is it possible?
That means, can I control the club's 3D position and orientation in animation from script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Inverse Kinematics (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html)

With this you attach the hands on the club and move the club as you want :
The hands / arms and close bones with follow it in a "realistic" way while the rest of the body will be animated as usual.

However the club movement will need some work to get a nice feeling like your original animations.

Target Matching (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TargetMatching.html) could be useful too or even better but I never used that.

Comment: Thanks @FLX, by the way you said "the club movement will need some work to get a nice feeling". What kind of work needs to be done for that?

Comment: Well, if you want a custom club movement like swing from the left, you'd have to do the rotation from script, and a simple linear interpolation might not be enought to be realistic : you need a custom acceleration to simulate the momentum